# Mostrar notificações em qualquer tela

Tags: android, android-notification

Tenho um aplicativo e quero fazer com que ele mostre uma notificação estilo pop-up, como o Whatsapp e/ou os lembretes do iOS, mas com um layout personalizado. Já procurei e até agora nada, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que esta resposta pode te ajudar. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696441/how-to-show-whatsapp-like-popup-notification-when-app-is-in-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696441/how-to-show-whatsapp-like-popup-notification-when-app-is-in-background)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html